# How to sync a dirty private git branch between personal workstations

Tags: git

I have a git repo on the internet and two workstations. Other developers have access to the git repo.

Workstation A is at the office and is not accessible from the internet, but can push/pull the git repo. Workstation B is at home.

I'm working on a private local branch on Workstation A and have to leave for home when it's in a dirty state. I want to continue working at home on Workstation B.

What is the best way to sync my dirty private branch to Workstation B?

EDIT:

In this context dirty means work that I don't think is complete. How would the flow differ for committed vs uncommitted work?

Comment: What does "in a dirty state" mean in this context? That you have uncommitted changes?

Comment: Can you describe your branching strategy? What would be the effect of committing work to a remote branch that is not complete, not tested, and may not be working (including possibly build-breaking)?

Comment: There is no downside to commiting the broken build to a feature branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I want to work on an unfinished change on another machine, I typically:

1. Create a branch: `$ git checkout -b feature/foobar`
2. Create a "WIP" commit: `$ git commit --all -m "WIP: Add feature foobar"`
3. Push the branch to the remote

And them from the other computer:

1. Fetch from the remote
2. Checkout my branch: `$ git checkout feature/foobar`
3. Finish the feature
4. Amend the previous commit: `$ git commit --all --amend`
5. Force push to overwrite the WIP commit on the remote: `$ git push -f`

**NOTE:** Only use this workflow (amend + force push) if you are the only one using the branch or are in direct communication with everyone else using this branch.

Comment: This is basically what I was thinking. One thing you can do to avoid the dangers of force pushing is to have a naming convention for work in progress *branches* - remember that branches are cheap! So you could use `retrodev-wip/feature/foobar`, rewrite history and force push at will, then push it as `feature/foobar` when you're ready for other people to see it.

Comment: Could you please explain why you're doing an --amend and push -f in steps 4 and 5?

Comment: @retrodev `--amend` adds the new changes into the previously WIP commit (which should also now get an updated commit message). Because this modifies the history, force-pushing is required.

Comment: @retrodev The "deeper" reason to use `--amend` is that you want to pretend to your colleagues that the intermediate WIP commit never happened - it was just your way of transporting the changes to a different computer, and wasn't a finished piece of work. If you're happy for it to show up as a commit in the final history, but just don't want people to *use* it yet, then the question has a much simpler answer: "Commit and push your changes to your branch, that's what branches are for."

Comment: Force push breaks the version on your home machine right?

Comment: @Ewan It breaks it in the sense that a simple "pull" will error, but not in the sense of you can't do anything ever again. At the point you're doing the force push, most likely you're never going to look at that branch again, it will be merged and deleted. If you do need it again, you can just delete your local branch on the home machine and check it out from the remote with its new rewritten history.

Comment: Why force? Cant you just commit the changes you made to make the code working and ignore all the commits with "non working code" inbetween?